# UIActionSheet iOS 8 not backwards compatible?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uiactionsheet

First, I know that in iOS 8, the UIActionSheet has been deprecated.

That said, an app that was compiled with an earlier SDK that contains a simple UIActionSheet **should** still present properly on iOS8.   I have several apps and in ALL of them so far, any UIActionSheet no longer shows properly on iOS 8.

Oddly enough, if I recompile with iOS 8 it shows fine.

Is anybody else seeing this or has anyone else reported this as a bug?  I would have expected more people to be commenting on this issue which is making me wonder if I'm doing something odd to cause the problem.

Here's the code for a simple action sheet and how it presents in iOS 7 and iOS 8.

```
UIButton *bn = (UIButton *)sender;
CGRect cr = [bn convertRect:bn.bounds toView:self.view];

UIActionSheet *as = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
for (int i=0; i < infoItems.count; i++){
    [as addButtonWithTitle:[infoItems objectAtIndex:i]];
}
[as showFromRect:cr inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

iOS 7:

[image]

iOS 8:

[image]

Nice, huh?

:(

Comment: Just as a test, pass `nil` for the title instead of `@""`. Also add a Cancel button after adding the other buttons. Any difference?

Comment: well, like I said, if I recompile with the iOS 8 SDK, it works fine.  My main beef is that this should be backwards compatible.  It's an issue for me because, to submit, I have to get new artwork since the app was done in 2011 before retina, 4" displays, etc.